# Is there anything like '\f' entity in html?

Tags: php, html

I was simply outputting a string using echo in php but it got altered and its not showing the exact string.I know about HTML entities little bit but not aware of anything called `\f` entity in HTML, or is something else causing the issue

```
<?php


$orig = "&lt;math&gt;x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + x \frac{dy}{dx} + (x^2 - \alpha^2)y = 0&lt;/math&gt;";

echo $orig;


?>
```

and the output is

```
<math>x^2 rac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + x rac{dy}{dx} + (x^2 - \alpha^2)y = 0</math>
```

Hope you noticed \frac changed to rac.What might be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\f is actually a `formfeed` in many languages although it's rarely used.
It's php, not html, that reads the string and changes it.
You can read about it here:http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Can you simply add a Space between `\` and `frac` ?

Comment: what exactly does it do ? simply skips and ignore it ?what's the point and when it comes useful?

Comment: It's made many years ago, when printers were mechanical monsters, not really used anymore, but still present in code.

Comment: any idea how to skip it and display ?

Comment: Like I wrote, add a Space.

Answer (score 0):

Just put &#92 instead of the backslash itself and you should have no problem. Example &#92frac

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more elaborative.